# How can I get a snapshot of my memory

Tags: c#, .net, profiling

Is there a way to know what objects eat my memory?

For example, for a given point in my code, I'd like to know how many strings are alive and how much memory they use.

Is there a tool or API for this?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, good'ol [windbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does that.

Answer (score 2):

The [CLR profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13382) does exactly this.  It's a great tool.